# geopandas cloropeth with two variables on map

Tags: pandas, geopandas

I have created a heatmap of oversupply or shortages of squash courts in Australia by Local Government Area (dark red being undersupply and dark green oversupply) using the following code:

## set a variable to plot court shortage

```
variable = "SHORTAGE"
```

> ## find the center points, copy our original df to a new df, and then set
>
> ## the geometry column to the newly created center points column
>
> ## (because a GeoPandas df can only have one geometry column)

```
merged_aus_map["center"] = merged_aus_map["geometry"].centroid
map_df_points = merged_aus_map.copy()
map_df_points.set_geometry("center", inplace = True)
```

## plot map of Australia with court shortage plotted using colormap red/yellow/green

```
AUS_Heatmap = merged_aus_map.plot(figsize = (40, 32),column=variable,cmap 
= 'RdYlGn', linewidth=0.8, edgecolor="0.8");
```

## Add labels on map of the name of the LGA

```
texts = []
for x, y, label in zip(map_df_points.geometry.x, map_df_points.geometry.y, 
map_df_points['LGA_NAME16']):
texts.append(plt.text(x, y, label, fontsize = 10))

aT.adjust_text(texts, force_points=0.3, force_text=0.8, expand_points=(1,1),
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color='grey', lw=0.5))
```

This is what is produced
[Australia map show over or undersupply of squash courts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b2Km.png)

I would like to overlay on the map above markers on each LGA that show squash facilities in that LGA coloured by the value in the last column of my dataframe (called Life cycle). If the life cycle value is 3 marker is red,2 = yellow, 1 = green and 0 = white (all with black outlines).

I have researched overlaying in geopandas maps but I don't quite get it. I am hoping someone could add to my code to achieve this

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: geopandas `.plot()` method returns a matplotlib Axes, so you just need to overlap your two Axes. See [method 2](http://geopandas.org/mapping.html#maps-with-layers)